# comparing a variable (that is repeatedly measured) between groups in R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, group-differences

I have a rather simple question (I hope) but for some reason I can't find the right/ a working answer anywhere on the web.

For my research I have measured mood on a scale 1-10, 6 times a day for 5 weeks. (thus a repeated measures design if i am not mistaken). The participants were assigned to three conditions based on anxiety scores (n= 15, 15, 5 respectively). What I want to do is comparing mood between the three groups to see if they differ.

I know I can't use a normal anova because the mood measurements aren't independable. and because I have over 6000 entries even the smallest difference is significant. I also tried calculating the mean mood of each particpant and then conduct the anova using just the mean mood of the participants, but then I lose so much.

What would be the correct way to test for group difference.

By the way: I am using R and the data frame is in a long format (rows = individual mood entries, column = mood rating and group)

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: If your hypothesis of interest is truly to compare "mood between the three groups to see if they differ" then a simple average might be all you need. But think carefully about the kinds of *specific* questions you would like to address (*before* looking at your data). Why did you collect 30 measurements per subject? What exactly are you worried that you are losing with simple means? Without more specific questions, it is unreasonable to suggest more specific analytic methods.

Comment: Well the idea of the study is as follows: we are trying to see if we can predict mood based on patterns in smartphone use. In order to do so we have tracked smartphone data from the participants (such as app use, data on sms, calls, gps etc) for a period of 5 weeks along with promted ecological momentary assesment, asking the participants to enter their mood 5 times each day for 5 weeks. We grouped the participants based on depression scores. I thought it would be nice to give an overview of mood per group and see if they differ.

Comment: as for what i am afraid of losing is that an anova on all the mood entries would yield significant results(probably due to the high N), but when i calculate a mean mood per participant over the whole period, i have a feeling i am not making optimal use of all the repeated measures that we did. (but it could be just a feeling i am having). So if i am correct, calculating the mean mood of the participants and then run an anova on the three groups would be the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to approach this would be a mixed model. That is, model mood as a function of group, with a random intercept for each subject. A simple example is shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33995/shouldnt-the-beta-estimates-always-be-the-same-using-lm-and-lmer), and this same link also explains when a simple anova (i.e. just using the subject means as you mentioned in your original post) will give equivalent parameter estimates and inferences.

Specifically, the results will be the same if your study is balanced (i.e. same number of observations per subject). Since missing a few data points here or there is inevitable, you should gain a little power by using the mixed model approach. The more unbalanced your data, the more power you should gain.

Spend some time learning about mixed models; you'll find they are very very useful. [Here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/random-regression-coefficients-using-lme4/) is a good link. Also, anything John Fox writes about mixed models (or nearly anything, really) I've found to be superb.

Comment: ahfoss thank you very much for your detailed information and the links. I will  definitely take a look at them.